# SELECT COUNT(*) throwing exception when queried

Tags: c#

I'm trying to query for the number of rows in a table, and get that back to my Controller Action. I'm using Dapper as my Micro-ORM and appear to be having some issues trying to achieve this.

#### Service Method

```
public Task<int> GetPostCount()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
    {
        return connection.QuerySingleAsync<int>(SqlQueries.Post.SelectPostCount);
    }
}
```

#### Controller Action

```
[HttpGet("Posts/{page:int?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Posts(int page)
{
    IEnumerable<PostHighlightViewModel> posts = await this.postService.GetAllPosts(postsPerPage, page < 1 ? 1 : page);
    if (posts.Count() == 0)
    {
        // BOOM goes the dynamite - right here.
        int numberOfPosts = await this.postService.GetPostCount();
        int pageToFetch = numberOfPosts / postsPerPage;
        posts = await this.postService.GetAllPosts(postsPerPage, pageToFetch);
    }

    return View("Index", posts);
}
```

The Sql I'm executing is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS
```

When I execute the query, I am given the following exception

> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60[13]
>         Connection id "0HKSQRDBQRA9E": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__110_0(Task`1 result)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__24`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at BlogWeb.Controllers.PostController.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\johnathonsullinger\Source\VSTS\Blog.Core\Source\BlogWeb\Controllers\PostController.cs:line 32
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.d__24`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler.<InvokeActionAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

There's not much for me to go off of here in order to try and figure out what happened. I can make other queries without any issues, but trying to query for the record count seems to be an issue.

I've tried using `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` and `QuerySingleAsync`. Should I not be using the `QueryAsync` family of methods?

Comment: Your `using` block may exit before the async call finishes. That's why the connection is closed I'm guessing. I could be wrong.

Comment: Hah! That was it. Completely failed to think of the fact the connection was being disposed while the async operation was happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection is disposed when execution returns from the `using` block, thus the connection is closed before the `async` operation can conclude.

You might consider closing the connection in `ContinueWith` to ensure it is closed when the `async` operation has finished.

Alternatively, I think you can use the `await` keyword on the async call.

Comment: I believe using the `await` keyword is the preferred/best practice

Comment: You're right that my returning the `Task` within my `using` statement was disposing of the connection. I am using `await` in most of the places within my services. In the areas where I don't actually need to act on the result set within the service, i avoid using await and just return the Task so I don't create the async state machine. Save a tiny bit of overhead. In this case, the difference between a `ContinueWith` and `await` is next to nothing so i'll opt for `await` for readability reasons. Thanks!